# Entity framework concurrency check: savechanges without incrementing the RowVersion

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, concurrency

I have a web form app which asks for confirmation after pressing on save button. (confirmation: save the record and shows everything that needs to be saved to the client)

the problem is that by pressing the save button I'm also doing some heavy operations on the record in another thread which save the record and causing the RowVersion to be changed to a new value.

Now when the user wants to submit the record he gets an OptimisticConcurrencyException

I was wondering if there is any solution to turn off the that increment for just one specific Savechanges() without using tsql in the background thread ?

Comment: If the first save changed Column A to value `BobA` and the second (currently) failing one changed Column A to value `BobB` - which one should win?

Comment: @mjwills both, but there is no easy way to update the web form with the new Rowversion after the second process gets done. that's why I'm looking for a way so the second process doesn't affect the Rowversion

Comment: **Both** is not an option. Do you want the final value to be `BobA` or `BobB` (i.e first one wins or last one wins)? Once we know that, we can give you some options.

Comment: Lets say process a never changes that specific column which process B will change, so there is no actual conflict here

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402826/entity-framework-optimisticconcurrencyexception-rethrown-after-refresh help?